# Python scrapy shell terminal KeyError: 'e'

Tags: python, scrapy

In my windows command prompt "python3 -m scrapy shell "https://scrapy.org"" works as expected and gives a interactive shell to work with as expected.

However if i open windows terminal and type "ubuntu" using windows subsystem for linux and then try to launch scrapy shell with "python3 -m scrapy shell 'https://scrapy.org'" or "scrapy shell 'https://scrapy.org'" i get the following error message:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/mnt/e/scrapy-project/miniscrapy/tutorial/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scrapy/__main__.py", line 4, in <module>
    execute()
  File "/mnt/e/scrapy-project/miniscrapy/tutorial/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 145, in execute
    _run_print_help(parser, _run_command, cmd, args, opts)
  File "/mnt/e/scrapy-project/miniscrapy/tutorial/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 100, in _run_print_help
    func(*a, **kw)
  File "/mnt/e/scrapy-project/miniscrapy/tutorial/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 153, in _run_command
    cmd.run(args, opts)
  File "/mnt/e/scrapy-project/miniscrapy/tutorial/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scrapy/commands/shell.py", line 68, in run
    crawler.engine = crawler._create_engine()
  File "/mnt/e/scrapy-project/miniscrapy/tutorial/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 101, in _create_engine
    return ExecutionEngine(self, lambda _: self.stop())
  File "/mnt/e/scrapy-project/miniscrapy/tutorial/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scrapy/core/engine.py", line 70, in __init__
    self.scraper = Scraper(crawler)
  File "/mnt/e/scrapy-project/miniscrapy/tutorial/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scrapy/core/scraper.py", line 71, in __init__
    self.itemproc = itemproc_cls.from_crawler(crawler)
  File "/mnt/e/scrapy-project/miniscrapy/tutorial/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scrapy/middleware.py", line 53, in from_crawler
    return cls.from_settings(crawler.settings, crawler)
  File "/mnt/e/scrapy-project/miniscrapy/tutorial/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scrapy/middleware.py", line 35, in from_settings
    mw = create_instance(mwcls, settings, crawler)
  File "/mnt/e/scrapy-project/miniscrapy/tutorial/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scrapy/utils/misc.py", line 156, in create_instance
    instance = objcls.from_crawler(crawler, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/mnt/e/scrapy-project/miniscrapy/tutorial/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scrapy/pipelines/media.py", line 68, in from_crawler
    pipe = cls.from_settings(crawler.settings)
  File "/mnt/e/scrapy-project/miniscrapy/tutorial/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scrapy/pipelines/images.py", line 105, in from_settings
    return cls(store_uri, settings=settings)
  File "/mnt/e/scrapy-project/miniscrapy/tutorial/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scrapy/pipelines/images.py", line 48, in __init__
    super(ImagesPipeline, self).__init__(store_uri, settings=settings,
  File "/mnt/e/scrapy-project/miniscrapy/tutorial/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scrapy/pipelines/files.py", line 361, in __init__
    self.store = self._get_store(store_uri)
  File "/mnt/e/scrapy-project/miniscrapy/tutorial/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scrapy/pipelines/files.py", line 409, in _get_store
    store_cls = self.STORE_SCHEMES[scheme]
KeyError: 'e'
```

in lib/python3.8/site-packages/scrapy/pipelines/files.py i added the following print messages to debug:

[image]

which prints:

uri:  E:/scrapy-project/miniscrapy/tutorial/images

_get_store pipelines/files scheme:  e

i already tried setting my path with "export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin" as well as storing it in ~/.bashrc. All python related libraries are installed with pip inside a virtual environment in the tutorial folder which contains the /images folders. I suppose the os.path.isabs() method functions when just running regular windows command prompt and somehow fails on my non-real ubuntu.

echo $PATH inside virtual environment:

/mnt/e/scrapy-project/miniscrapy/tutorial/env/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games

Comment: Are you sure “E:/scrapy-project/miniscrapy/tutorial/images” is a valid path within the Ubuntu subsystem? What happens if you run `ls E:/scrapy-project/miniscrapy/tutorial/images` from the ubuntu subsystem?

Comment: ls E:/scrapy-project/miniscrapy/tutorial/images inside the venv returns No such file or directory while ls /mnt/e/scrapy-project/miniscrapy/tutorial/images inside the venv is able to find the folder with all sub-folders

Comment: What’s the value of your `IMAGES_STORE` setting? It sounds like it contains the Windows path, but should contain the Ubuntu path when running your spider in Ubuntu.

Comment: **IMAGES_STORE** was indeed set to  **'E:/scrapy-project/miniscrapy/tutorial/images'** instead of **'/mnt/e/scrapy-project/miniscrapy/tutorial/images'**. i tried to change the path and now got other unexpected behaviour.

When i now try to run both **python3 -m scrapy shell 'https://scrapy.org'** and **scrapy shell 'https://scrapy.org'** inside the venv it tries to start running spiders in my project folder. It should not do this and instead only open the website in my terminal to practise all the response.xpath commands

Comment: i had some unrelated package imports thats got resolved now in my project. But yes updating the IMAGES_STORE path to the ubuntu required path in my settings.py solved the problem. thanks alot, now "python3 -m scrapy shell 'https://scrapy.org'" works as intended in my ubuntu environment